# Customed table primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

please i need help, i want to know if the foreign key generated from **appointment table** would be mapped to **patients** and **physicians** tables with the code below

```
patients table 

create_table :patients, primary_key: :pat_id, id: :string do |t|
    t.string :name
end



physicians table

create_table :physicians, primary_key: :phys_id, id: :string do |t|
    t.string :name
end


appointment table

create_table :appointments, id:false do |t|
    t.belongs_to :patient, primary_key: :pat_id, foreign_key: :pat_id, index: true
    t.belongs_to :physician, primary_key: :phys, foreign_key: :pat_id, index: true
    t.datetime :appointment_date
end
```

when the table for **appointments** is generated i see **patient_id** and **physician_id** instead of **pat_id** and **phys_id**.
Am curious, please would this till map **patients_id** to **pat_id** and **physicians_id** to **phys_id**?

Answer (score 0):

`belongs_to` in **TableDefinition** is an [alias for `references`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/88aa2efd692619e87eee88dfc48d608bea9bcdb4/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb#L421).

Use `t.belongs_to :pat` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the your answer, but i don't understand what you meant by **belongs_to in TableDefinition is an alias for references**

Comment: please can you explain further? so i can really understand, as am just starting RoR@Shalev Shalit

Comment: yes, references( / belongs_to) is the function to use in creating a new column in the table. The only thing it does is creating a new **integer** column with **_id** at the end. `@base.add_column(@table_name, "#{col}_id", :integer, options)`